# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable only when a maps fragment is present in the layout file

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm getting this error **only** when my layout file contains a map fragment like the one specified below as described in the [android v2 api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment), variants included ie. specifying the class name in a *android:name* attribute etc..

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/places_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**However** I **don't** get this error when i add the fragment **programmatically** ie. When i create a SupportMapFragment object in code and add it to a "fragment container" element in the layout file.

The fact that it's working when added programmatically makes me rule out "build path" errors as suggested in most proposed solutions on SO - and i also carefully followed the steps,  again and again ie. adding google play services as a project, specifying it in Properties -> Android -> Project (i have a green tick) and **not** adding google play services as a jar etc..

Has anyone had this particular problem? Especially the "working when added programmatically" and "not working when added as a fragment element in the layout file" problem?

Regards

Comment: For the case while adding map fragment to layout, hope you are using the below code 'GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();' to create a google map object and this code should be inside or after onResume()

Comment: Yes I'm doing exactly that. However, the error occurs when the setContentView(layout) method is called and that because the layout file contains a map fragment.

Comment: Same is happening to me. Did you fix? I am using Android Studio. I tried everything with no luck. No error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a lot of going back and forth I compiled the google_play_services module and all of the sudden everything work. Try it and let me know if it worked